# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '-'. I am missing something

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error

Could someone please explain to me why I am getting this error? I know it has something to do with the DB name having a dash in it.

```
declare @dname varchar(80)
declare @cmnd varchar(2000)

DECLARE get_db CURSOR FOR
   select name from sysdatabases where dbid > 9

open get_db
FETCH NEXT from get_db into @dname
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
          set @cmnd = 'if (select count(name) from ' + @dname + '.dbo.sysobjects where name = ''SQLLOG'')=1 begin TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @dname + '.dbo.sqllog end'
          exec (@cmnd)
          --print @cmnd
FETCH NEXT from get_db into @dname
end
close get_db
deallocate get_db
```

Comment: If the database name isn't a proper identifier you must escape it, try: ` ... from [' + @dname + '].dbo.sysobjects...`

Comment: Use [`quotename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx). That deals correctly with embedded `]` too.

Answer (score 0):

`@dname` will hold values from `sysdatabases`. If one of the databases contains `-`, then you need to either enclose the variable into ` or use `quotename`. Basically, whenever you run a string as a command, you need to make sure that there are no possible problems, especially if the data was added by users.

```
set @cmnd = 'if (select count(name) from `' + @dname + '`.dbo.sysobjects where name = 'SQLLOG')=1 begin TRUNCATE TABLE `' + @dname + '`.dbo.sqllog end'
```

or

```
set @cmnd = 'if (select count(name) from quotename(\'' + @dname + '\').dbo.sysobjects where name = 'SQLLOG')=1 begin TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @dname + '.dbo.sqllog end'
```